# Rewriterule in.htaccess stopped PHP scripts from working, stopped loading images, and stopped loading css

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I created 2 dynamic pages, the first being a profile page, and the second being a city page. Both pages are essentially powered by a query with the data coming from the URL, ie. `root/profile.php?userid=user and root/finder.php?state=state&city=city`.

My plan was to rewrite the URLs of these pages `root/profile/user` and `root/state/city` into `root/profile.php?userid=user` and `root/finder.php?state=state&city=city` so the query gets resolved and then displayed on a nice looking URL.

1. Visitors click on the link, `root/profile/user` (non-existent page)
2. .htaccess rewrites the URL in the server and turns the requested page into `root/profile?userid=user`
3. Query is returned and displayed on `root/profile/user`

**File structure:**

Root

```
 - index
 - header
 - footer
 - .htaccess
 - login page
 - sign up page
 - sql connection
 - script
 - image upload
```

Root/css

```
- CSS file
```

Root/includes

```
- login function
- logout function
- sign up function
- all other functions
```

What's weird about this is as soon as I turn `RewriteEngine on`, everything goes haywire immediately. Without even typing `root/profile/user` or `root/state/city` (which I assume is only when the server handles the rewrite thereby messing things up). The same is true the other way around. After I comment out RewriteEngine and save .htaccess, it immediately starts working again from the index page.

Can you guys help me understand where I'm going wrong with this? Or, at the very least, which concept I'm missing? Here's the RewriteRule I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) profile.php?userid=$1
RewriteRule  ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) city_page.php?state=$1&city=$2
```

I'm totally new to PHP and servers, and more so with RegEx, so please excuse my sheer lack of knowledge. If there's a better way to create a dynamically generated URL, you can just point me to the right direction and I'll study it.

Appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# profile user rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?userid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# state city rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^([\w+)/([\w-]+)/?$ city_page.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Keep in mind that with these rewrite rules, your relative links for css/js/images may not work correctly. For that to work, you can add this directive just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: That worked! You're incredible! Can you tell me why it wasn't working the first time? I just want to understand what I did wrong so I could avoid having the same problem again.

Comment: There could me multiple reasons. Not using `<base` tag and/or absence of first rule that skips files and directories from rewrite